# Leer varias lineas con Stdin.readlines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una duda con Stdin.readlines, no estoy seguro de como se usa; por ejemplo yo tengo este parrafo

> Adventures in Disneyland Two blondes were going to Disneyland when
>   they came to a fork in the road. The sign read: "Disneyland Left." So
>   they went home.

Pero al imprimirlo me sale asi:

```
['Adventures in DisneylandTwo blondes were going to Disneyland when they came to  fork in the road. The sign read: "Disneyland Left." So they went home.\n', '\n']
```

Mi idea era que cada palabra estuviera separada como un elemento, pero aquí un elemento es una frase, Mi entrada es `Mensaje=stdin.readlines()`, pero no se como usar esto muy bien, he intentado ponerle un `split()` o un `strip()` pero esto me lanza un error de atributo.

Alguien me puede explicar bien como funciona `stdin.readlines()` y que atributos tiene?

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `readlines()` (ya sea sobre `stdin` o sobre otro fichero), lo que te retorna es una **lista**, cuyos elementos son las líneas leídas. No separa por frases, como has dicho, sino por retornos de carro. Cada vez que en la entrada aparece un retorno de carro, eso da por terminada una línea y esa línea se añade a la lista que finalmente será retornada.

Cuando intentas aplicar `split()` sobre lo que te devuelve `readlines()` lógicamente te da un error, porque lo que devuelve es una lista que no tiene método `split()`.

Si lo que quieres es recibir una lista de *palabras* en lugar de líneas, la solución más sencilla es leer el archivo completo con `read()`, y ya que en este caso recibirás una cadena, aplicar el método `split()` sobre ella, para dividirla en palabras. Si a `split()` no le pasas parámetros, usará espacios o retornos de carro indistintamente como separadores de palabras.

```
palabras = sys.stdin.read().split()
```

Ten en cuenta no obstante una cosa. Estás leyendo de la entrada estándar, por lo que la línea anterior no retornará la lista de palabras hasta que la entrada estándar se haya "agotado" (leído por completo). Cuando ejecutas el script redirigiendo la entrada desde un fichero, esto ocurrirá al llegar al final del fichero, que es lo que queremos. Pero si lo ejecutas en modo interactivo, el usuario tendrá que ir tecleando todas las líneas, usando retornos de carro si quiere para separar las líneas, y pulsando finalmente Ctrl+D para indicar el fin de la entrada. Mientras no se pulse Ctrl+D, el programa seguirá esperando datos de `stdin`.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me fue muy util!